# searching patterns in one column, multiple rows

Tags: excel, vba

In excel, I have a column with these values:

```
3
6
9
12
9
12
6
9
```

Now I want to find patterns "9 \n 12". The conventional find menu doesn't do that. Is there anyway to implement such method?

Comment: Why do you need to do this? Is it because each cell should only contain 1 value but some cells have two values (e.g. 9 and 12) and you want to be able to place them in a single cell each?

Comment: Are you searching for `Cell(R,"A").Value=9` and `Cell(R+1,"A").Value=12`.  I do not believe this is possible.  You would need to search for 9 then continue the search if the next cell down was not 12.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

- Menu Edit > Find
- Type `9`
- Then, hold down alt and type `010` (might have to try with `013` too)
- Release alt key
- Type `12`

It should work